# Can't see anything outside pyramid

Tags: modeling, interface

I can't remember what keys I pressed, but for some reason I can't see anything of model outside of this pyramid. Any help on how I can get rid of it and see my model again would be helpful. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set a Clipping Border - probably by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Simply press that same key combination again to clear it or go to the View menu and select Clipping Border.